# Find max and min from file loop

Tags: java, file, int, max, min

i need to find the max and min ints from this file i wrote a for loop to the file now i need a way to read the max and min using file streams

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter("numbers.dat");
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("numbers.dat");

    DataInputStream data = new DataInputStream(in);

    try (DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("numbers.dat"))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            output.write(i);

        }
        output.close();

    }
```

Comment: What is your question, and what this code do, can you explain a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

In response to 'i need to find the max and min ints from this file', simply process with a `for` loop to find the largest and the smallest numbers.

```
int[] integers;  // Your integers in an array, however you loaded them.
int max;         // To hold the maximum integer found.
int min;         // To hold the minimum integer found.

    for (int element : integers) {
        // If it's bigger, update.
        if (element > max) {
            max = element;
        }

        // If it's smaller, update.
        if (element < min) {
            min = element;
        }
    }
}
```

In response to 'i wrote a for loop to the file now i need a way to read the max and min using file streams', you have to load the file into memory.

Now, I don't see how you would do that with the manner that you've printed the file (or at least, how you intend to write the file in the code given) without any kind of delimiter (such as a `,` or `\n`).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest parsing the file into a list of Integers.

If you parsing the file into a list of Integer's you can get min and max with the following:

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// Populate the list from the entries in the file
...
// Get the min and max
Integer min = Collections.min(l);
Integer max = Collections.max(l);
System.out.println("min=" + min + "; max=" + max);
```

To determine how you create a list of integers from the file it would be helpful to know the format of the file.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but I'm not sure the contents of all "dat" files are equal. If you open it in a text editor what does the content look like?

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code, you need to call output.**writeInt**(i) not write(i)

```
private static void doRead() throws IOException
{
    final PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter("numbers.dat");

    try (DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("numbers.dat"))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            output.writeInt(i);  // do writeInt(i) not write(i)
        }
    }

    try ( FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("numbers.dat");
          DataInputStream data = new DataInputStream(in) )
    {

        final ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(SIZE);

        for( int i=0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            list.add( data.readInt() );
        }

        final int max = list.stream()
            .max( (a, b) -> Integer.compare( a, b ) )
            .get();

        final int min = list.stream()
            .min( (a, b) -> Integer.compare( a, b ) )
            .get();

        System.out.println("max=" + max);
        System.out.println("min=" + min);
    }
}
```